# wma audio stream to mp3 stream using NAudio c#

Tags: c#-4.0, naudio, lame, wma

My task is to convert wma audio stream to mp3 stream using NAudio and Lame. The below code is working fine with file name but I want it to be done with memory stream. I search in NAudio there is no method for reading wma audio stream. Is it possible with NAudio?

```
    public static byte[] ConvertWmaToMp3(uint bitrate = 128)
    {

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\sample.wma", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);            
        var ws = new NAudio.WindowsMediaFormat.WMAFileReader(fs.Name);                                    

        // Setup encoder configuration
        WaveLib.WaveFormat fmt = new WaveLib.WaveFormat(ws.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 16, ws.WaveFormat.Channels);
        Yeti.Lame.BE_CONFIG beconf = new Yeti.Lame.BE_CONFIG(fmt, bitrate);

        // Encode WAV to MP3
        int blen = ws.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[blen];
        byte[] mp3data = null;

        using (MemoryStream mp3strm = new MemoryStream())
        using (Mp3Writer mp3wri = new Mp3Writer(mp3strm, fmt, beconf))
        {
            int rc;
            while ((rc = ws.Read(buffer, 0, blen)) > 0)
            {
                mp3wri.Write(buffer, 0, rc);
            }

            mp3data = mp3strm.ToArray();
        }

        return mp3data;                      

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the `WMAFileReader` class doesn't support reading data from a stream.  The WMA APIs support reading WMA from an `IStream` so it is definitely possible.

If you want to implement streaming yourself you'll need to grab the source code for [`WmaFileReader`](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudio.WindowsMediaFormat/WmaFileReader.cs) and [`WmaStream`](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudio.WindowsMediaFormat/Interop/WmaStream.cs) from CodePlex, and use them as templates for your modified classes.

First thing you'll need is a wrapper class that provides a COM `IStream` interface to a .NET `Stream`.  Here's a simple one:

```
public class InteropStream : IStream, IDisposable
{
    public readonly Stream intern;

    public InteropStream(Stream strm)
    {
        intern = strm;
    }

    ~InteropStream()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool final)
    {
        if (final)
            intern.Dispose();
    }

    #region IStream Members
    public void Clone(out IStream ppstm)
    {
        ppstm = null;
    }

    public void Commit(int grfCommitFlags)
    {
        intern.Flush();
    }

    readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    public void CopyTo(IStream pstm, long cb, IntPtr pcbRead, IntPtr pcbWritten)
    {
        if (pcbRead != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbRead, 0);
        if (pcbWritten != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbWritten, 0);
    }

    public void LockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType)
    { }

    public void Read(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbRead)
    {
        int rc = intern.Read(pv, 0, cb);
        if (pcbRead != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbRead, rc);
    }

    public void Revert()
    { }

    public void Seek(long dlibMove, int dwOrigin, IntPtr plibNewPosition)
    {
        long origin = 0;
        if (dwOrigin == 1) // STREAM_SEEK_CUR
            origin = intern.Position;
        else if (dwOrigin == 2) // STREAM_SEEK_END
            origin = intern.Length;

        long pos = origin + dlibMove;
        intern.Position = pos;

        if (plibNewPosition != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.WriteInt64(plibNewPosition, pos);
    }

    public void SetSize(long libNewSize)
    { }

    public void Stat(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG pstatstg, int grfStatFlag)
    {
        var res = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG();

        res.type = 2; // STGTY_STREAM
        res.cbSize = intern.Length;

        pstatstg = res;
    }

    public void UnlockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType)
    { }

    public void Write(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbWritten)
    { }
    #endregion
}
```

Next copy the `WmaStream` code to a new namespace in your project and add the following code to the top of the class:

```
    InteropStream interopStrm = null;

    public WmaStream(Stream fileStream)
        : this(fileStream, null)
    { }

    public WmaStream(Stream fileStream, WaveFormat OutputFormat)
    {
        interopStrm = new InteropStream(fileStream);
        m_reader = WM.CreateSyncReader(WMT_RIGHTS.WMT_RIGHT_NO_DRM);
        try
        {
            IWMSyncReader2 rdr = m_reader as IWMSyncReader2;
            rdr.OpenStream(interopStrm);
            Init(OutputFormat);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                m_reader.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            m_reader = null;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Do the same with `WmaFileReader` and the following code:

```
    public WMAFileReader(Stream wmaStream)
    {
        m_wmaStream = new WmaStream2(wmaStream);
        m_waveFormat = m_wmaStream.Format;
    }
```

Now you can create an instance of your modified `WmaFileReader` using either a filename or a `Stream` instance - `MemoryStream`, `FileStream`, etc.  The `Stream` instance needs to be readable and seekable.

I've tried the above on a few random WMA files I found on my computer, loaded into `MemoryStream` or using `FileStream`, and it works as I expected it to.

Presumably Mark is working on adding this functionality to the NAudio.Wma package, so consider this an interim fix until NAudio supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert WMA to MP3 with NAudio is to use the Media Foundation based classes. If you are on Windows 8 and above, and MP3 encoder should be available.

```
using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader("test.wma"))
{
    MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(reader, "test.mp3");
}
```

On systems without an MP3 encoder, I tend to use LAME.exe and stream the input audio through stdin. See [my article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET) for more info on this approach.