# NAudio MediaFoundationRecorder EncodeToAAC Byte array instead of file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, audio, naudio

What I'm currently doing is while recording I get the bytes from the data received event and encode the bytes with a codec. The codecs I have set up to currently use are ALaw, G722, GSM, etc (like in the [NetworkChatDemo](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioDemo/NetworkChatDemo/INetworkChatCodec.cs))

The code used to start recording

```
    If waveIn Is Nothing Then
        waveIn = New WaveIn
        waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0
        waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 100
        waveIn.WaveFormat = codec.RecordFormat
        waveIn.StartRecording()
    End If
```

The code used to work with the recorded bytes

```
Private Sub OnDataAvailable(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WaveInEventArgs) Handles waveIn.DataAvailable
    Dim encoded As Byte() = codec.Encode(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded)
    ...
    //Send encoded audio over UdpClient
End Sub
```

This is working well for me but I'd like to add support for the AAC format. So I'd like to achieve the same result as in the above DataReceived event, a byte array of encoded AAC audio which I can send over udp, from `MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToAac(...)` or another class/function I am not aware of within NAudio. As far as I can tell, `MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToAac(...)` only encodes audio to a file and not a byte array. It also doesn't accept a byte array as a parameter. Is there a way to achieve what I want or does NAudio only let me work with an AAC file after it has been fully recorded and saved?

Comment: A lot of this stuff is new in NAudio.  The Media Foundation library does appear to allow for stream-based encoding (according to the documentation for `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL`), so I expect that Mark will build that functionality into NAudio at some stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as Corey says, this is a new addition to NAudio for 1.7, and adding support to encode to a Stream is something I would definitely like to add in the future.

If you don't mind working at a lower level, you could try to construct the AAC encoder as a MFT creating a derived class from `MediaFoundationTransform` (see `MediaFoundationResampler` as an example of how to do this.

Comment: Does it use `IStream` or another form?  If `IStream` then the `InteropStream` I banged up for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421460 might be useful - I can flesh it out if you like.

Comment: It's an IMFByteStream

Comment: @MarkHeath I know this is an old question but I have been studying NAudio for a little while and still cannot figure out how to do this with NAudio. Has there been anything new in NAudio regarding this feature since? I am working on a UWP app and have installed NAudio.UAP.