# Is there a way to play a stream of AAC with NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio, aac, m4a

The only thing I found was with `MediaFoundationReader` which seems to work only with files. But I want to play a stream, not a file. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAudio's Media Foundation support is quite new, so not everything is supported as yet.  Unfortunately stream-based playback is one of the features that isn't supported yet.

Check out [this answer from Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19631848/920669) to a similar question about MF support for streams.

If you're keen to get in and implement it yourself you will need to create a wrapper class that implements the `IMFByteStream` interface, then adapt the NAudio `MediaFoundationReader` class to use streams.  I did something similar [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19463486/920669) for the `WmaFileReader` and `WmaStream` classes to use a stream-based source for NAudio's `Windows Media Audio` support.

Comment: The thing is that I'm pretty new to NAudio and that would be a very hard task for me. Also, seems like the code needs seekable stream, and I'm using GetResponseStream() from HttpWebResponse, so the stream isn't seekable, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Just, after two more years since the last comment, I stumbled upon this question. I assume the OP's software is C#, as he wants to use NAudio.

Exactly that is done in the [QIRX SDR](http://www.softsyst.com/qirx) (Open Source, I'm the author), by using P/Invoke and a suitable wrapper,without using IMFByteStream.