# "MPEG audio header not found" error when opening with TagLib after converting with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, taglib-sharp

I converted a wma file simply by doing something like this...

```
ffmpeg -i song.wma -f mp3 song.mp3
```

I can then play the mp3 file in Windows Media player, so it looks like the conversion worked.

However, if I try to open the file in TagLib, I get an error "MPEG audio header not found" on the following line...

```
TagLib.File tf = TagLib.File.Create("song.mp3");
```

I've tried this on a few wma files, so it's not just that one that's at fault.

Anyone have any idea what I did wrong? I find the docs for ffmpeg pretty overwhelming, and as a complete ignoramus in the field of audio encoding, I haven't a clue what most of it means. Could be I'm missing something in the conversion, although that wouldn't explain why WMP can play it but TagLib can't open it.

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command. Does an output from `lame` work? `ffmpeg -i input.wma -f wav - | lame - output.mp3`

Comment: How do I show the output? This little box will only allow a few hundred characters, and the output is more than that. Also, I'm not sure how to run lame, as I don't have it as a standalone executable (as far as I know). I thought it was wrapped up in ffmpeg. Sorry to be dumb, but as I said, I'm a rank beginner in this stuff! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Windows 7 Pro x64 SP1

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Copying the command prompt output isn't a problem, I just piped it into a text file. The problem is that the silly little comments on this site don't allow much text, and don't allow any line breaks, so I can't paste it all in.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? Seemed like a reasonable enough question to me? Please can whoever downvoted it explain what I did wrong.

Comment: I meant that you should update your question with the requested info; not attempt to cram it all in small comments.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Ah, good idea, didn't think of that. Was that the reason for the downvote, or was that someone else?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks for the clarification. I wonder who did and why? Seems like a reasonable enough question to me.

Comment: Probably because you did not provide enough information such as the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not strictly an answer to my original question, I managed to get another way of doing what I wanted.

Please see Corey's answer to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31239359/706346), in which he shows how to use his NAudio package to convert the file in code. This is a better approach anyway, as it doesn't rely on running external programs, which was causing its own problems. The converted file produced by his package ran through TagLib without any issues.